# $firebase with userid reference, init after user login best practice?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Just like firefeed, i'm storing user-meta under /users/userid.

I only need the meta for the currently logged in user, so my thinking is to grab a reference only for the logged in user. So instead of

`usersRef = new Firebase(firebase/users/) && users = $firebase(usersRef)`

i'm waiting until the login service sets the current user, and then created the reference based on that user's id. This is inside of a service.

```
    var userRef = undefined;
    var user = undefined;

var _setCurrentUser = function (passedUser) {
        console.log(passedUser);
        currentUser = passedUser;
        if (!currentUser) {
        userRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URI + 'users/' + currentUser.id);
        user = $firebase(userRef);
        }
    };
```

My question is: Is this a good idea? If i don't need a reference to the entire users object, does it make sense performance-wise to specify a specific user. How so/in what way? Is there a better way to wait until we have the current user's id to create the firebase instance for the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, if you don't need all users, you would fetch the specific reference. Something like the following:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['firebase']);

// a little abstraction to manage establishing a $firebaseSimpleLogin instance
app.factory('loginService', function($firebaseSimpleLogin, Firebase) {
   var fb = new Firebase(URL);
   var auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(fb);
   return auth;
});

// a little abstraction to reduce the deps involved in creating a $firebase object
app.factory('syncData', function($firebase, Firebase) {
   return function(pathToData) {
      return $firebase(new Firebase(URL).child(pathToData));
   }
});

app.factory('logInAndReturnUser', function(loginService, syncData) {
   return function(provider) {
      // call the login service
      return loginService.$login(provider)
         .then(function(user) {
            // resolve to a $firebase object for the specific user
            return syncData('users/'+user.uid);
         });
   }
});
```

Angular-ui's [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) is ideal for this sort of use case and I highly recommend this approach for dealing with auth. Simply set up a `resolve` that returns the user:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['firebase']);

app.factory('loginService', function($firebaseSimpleLogin, Firebase) {
   var fb = new Firebase(URL);
   var auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(fb);
   return auth;
});

app.configure(function($stateProvider) {
   $stateProvider.state('home', {
      url: '/',
      resolve: {
        'user': function(loginService) {
           // getCurrentUser returns a promise that resolves to the user object
           // or null if not logged in
           return loginService.$getCurrentUser();
        }
      },
      controller: 'homeCtrl'
    })
});

app.controller('homeCtrl', function(user) {
   // assumes we've logged in already, that can be part of router
   // processing or we could check for user === null here and send to login page
   console.log('user is ' + user.uid); 
});
```